# How can I hide a single appliction in the xfce taskbar?

Tags: xfce, taskbar, xfce-panel

Cisco's Anyconnect - when running - has both an icon in the *tray* and in the *taskbar*.

The tray icon as everything that I need and therefore I'd like to *not* have the Anyconnect client show up in the taskbar to leave space for other applications that I launch.

Is this possible and could you please show me how?

[image]